# How Can I Make A ForLoop in Windows and Insert with Single Quotes Around the For-Each Operator

Tags: powershell

So I have a weird task, I am trying to clean up my AD Membership and I need to write a for-loop for the task. We have groups that are assigned to a group, and we are trying to remove the groups from groups as nest groups are not supported. I have a good for-loop that currently works:

Main Command:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select-Object -Property Name
```

The above command gives me a list of all of the Domain Groups.
I want to take this list and iterate over it showing me the group memebership.

With ForEach-Object Statement:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_}
```

This doesn't work, because I can't get the `group_name` string to be returned into the `$_` with single quotes. Instead, I need to return a single quote around the `$_` operator so that it returns the `group_name` in `'group_name'`.

How can I get single quotes to return around the `group_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the statement:

```sh
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ }
```

Is that `$_` refers to an object which's **Property is `Name`** and `Get-ADGroupMember` doesn't know how to deal with said object, if instead, you were referring to the **Property Value of the object** it should work correctly:

```sh
... | ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name }
```

It's important to note that, `Select-Object` in this case, is not needed at all and is only slowing your script down and furthermore, if you want to find **all groups having a nested group as member** you could use a filtering cmdlet such as `Where-Object`:

```sh
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Where-Object {
    (Get-ADGroupMember $_.DistinguishedName).where({ $_.ObjectClass -eq 'group' }, 'First')
}
```